# adding a new column in a dataframe based on another dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, merge

Let's assume we have the following 2 dataframes:

```
df1(36000, 20) and  df2(80,6)
They have 3 columns in common(let's say Name, Last Name, Date)
```

df1 includes the data of df2 (minus the data in the 3 different columns) and of course some extra information.
df2 has a column that I am interested (let' s name it Rent)

What I want is to create an extra column in df1 that for the values that of df2 to have the value "Overdue" and for the values that are not there have "Due" while keeping the rest of columns in df1.
I tried the following

```
  merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=list(df1.columns),
                                   indicator=True)
    df1['Rent'] = np.where(merged['_merge'] == 'both', 'Overdue', 'Due')
```

However I get an error due to the fact that not all columns of df1 exist in df2. Any ideas?

Also I tried the following

```
    df1['Rent'].apply(lambda x: 'Overdue' if df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name']) else 'Due')
```

but I m getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'df2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1['Rent'] = lambda x: 'Overdue' if df1['Name'].isin(df2['Name']) else 'Due'
```

The main point is not to use .apply()

Comment: Hey! Thank you for replying. When I am applying the aforementioned code a new cell is indeed created but the values inside are something like the following : <function score>.<locals>.<lambda> at and then a memory location I assume?